# cytoscape.js arbor layout on jsbin

Tags: javascript, cdn, cytoscape.js

I am trying to do a lightweight "lab" using cytoscape.js on JSBin, and am only having problems with the arbor layout. I have been pounding on my [nonworking example](http://jsbin.com/fisif/9/edit), and after dropping in a script that works on a server and then fails, I'm thinking I've run into a different twist on the classic 'arbor not working' problem.

I know the answer to that question is to use the cytoscape.js version of arbor.js. But, what is described in the [admonition](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#layouts/arbor), doesn't work on JSBin. So, my question is how to get to this version of the script without having the option of loading the script from the site, and in a way that JS novices might be able to replicate.

Specifically, I can use the script tag

```
<script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
```

in my html and get other layouts, but is there a comparable resource for the cytoscape.js version of `arbor.js`?

*After pounding a little harder, I confirmed that my hanging JSBin is due to something missing in the orginal arbor.js; and it seems the answer to my question is that there can't be such a thing because of technicalities with web workers -- arbor.js has to be local.*

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/arbor.js

But there's no guarantee that or similar URLs might change or disappear in future.  They're used for the docs and (I think) some examples, but they certainly should not be used in production environments.